# Swift globals and global functions in objective c

Tags: objective-c, swift, global-variables

the documentation says:

> Global constants defined in C and Objective-C source files are automatically imported by the Swift compiler as Swift global constants.

But it doesn't say anything about the other way around. I need to define a global swift constant and be able to see it one the objective c side like a global c constant. Like on the swift side define:

```
public let CARDS = ["card1", "card2"]
```

and see use it on the objective c side like

```
NSLog(@"Cards count: %d", [CARDS count])
```

What should I do? I've already imported the swift automatically generated header like:

```
#import "MyProject-Swift.h"
```

and in Xcode if I `command-click` on it, it takes me to the correct place in the swift code, but at compile time I get:

```
'User of undeclared Identifier CARDS'
```

on my objective c side.

Comment: Globals defined in Swift cannot currently be used with Objective-C

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[Here is the document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_86) about it

> You’ll have access to anything within a class or protocol that’s
>   marked with the @objc attribute as long as it’s compatible with
>   Objective-C. This excludes Swift-only features such as those listed
>   here:
>
> - Generics
> - Tuples
> - Enumerations defined in Swift
> - Structures defined in Swift
> - Top-level functions defined in Swift
> - Global variables defined in Swift
> - Typealiases defined in Swift
> - Swift-style variadics
> - Nested types
> - Curried functions

Global variables (including constants) are unaccessible from Objective-C.

Instead, you have to declare a class which has accessors for the global constants.

```
// Swift
public let CARDS = ["card1", "card2"]

@objc class AppConstant {
   private init() {}
   class func cards() -> [String] { return CARDS }
}

// Objective-C
NSArray *cards = [AppConstant cards];
```

Comment: Wow apple... so much for interoperability. More like have to write hacky classes in swift for every nice thing that swift can do naturally. Apple please fix this

Comment: Another option is to create a header file in Objective-C that contains all constants shared between Objective-C and Swift, and import that in any Objective-C files that need access to the constants as well as the project's bridging header.

Comment: That "This excludes Swift-only features such as those listed here:" bit is galling. Global variables and global/top level functions are not swift-only features. I can create a global function in C or Objective-C and it's visible in Swift, but I can't do the reverse.

Comment: `Only classes that inherit from NSObject can be declared @objc` so you will need `: NSObject` for your class, and add `override` to the init()

Comment: It's 2020 and the interoperability between Swift, ObjC, ObjC++, C++, and C is still very complex and non-intuitive, and weakly documented.  With all 4 in our project, solving continual interop problems has cost us weeks of development calendar time -- but we're still ahead of hardware.  haha

Answer (score 8):

Nice answer by @rintaro, but another alternative simple Swift answer for constants that can be used in both Swift and Objective-C:

```
@objcMembers
class MyConstants: NSObject {
    static let kMyConstant1 = "ConstantValue1";
    static let kMyConstant2 = "ConstantValue2";
    static let CARDS = ["card1", "card2"]
}
```

You can access this on both Swift and Objective-C by:

```
MyConstants.kMyConstant1 // this will return "ConstantValue1"
MyConstants.CARDS // this will return array ["card1", "card2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift global functions (ie. swift top-level functions) cannot be accessed by objC.  Period. End of story.

See above answer from rintaro, to wit...
"This excludes Swift-only features such as those listed here:
. . .
Top-level functions defined in Swift"

boom