# How do I expose a Swift global function to Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I have created a debug version of the Swift print command called `debugPrint()` that takes a few extra parameters that let my apps filter their console output at runtime based (e.g. turn on `init` & `deinit` print statements from a given module while debugging something, then turn it back off.)

The app I'm working on contains a fair amount of legacy Objective-C code, so I'd like to be able to use an Objective-C interface to the same debug print function.

I want to expose an Objective-C version, probably called `dLog`, to correspond with `NSLog`, that does the same thing for Objective-C.

However, I can't figure out how to expose a Swift global function to Objective-C. It's straightforward to expose `@objc` swift classes, along with their static methods and instance methods, but this will be an app-wide global function, not specific to any particular class.

Comment: Compare [Swift globals in objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26463487/2976878) – top-level Swift functions are not compatible with Obj-C.

Comment: So I can define top-level functions in C or Objective-C that are visible in C, Objective-C and Swift, but I can't define top-level functions in Swift and use them in C-Objective-C? That's nuts.

Comment: Discussed on swift-evolution: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20170327/034746.html (without any resolution yet, as far as I can see)

Comment: @Hamish, can you post your reply as an answer so I can accept it/up-vote it? "You can't do that" appears to be the correct answer. Not the answer I wanted, but the correct answer nonetheless.

Comment: @MartinR, while it's true that the answer to my question is covered in the answer to the "duplicate" you linked, I submit that my question has value and should remain open. I was asking about Swift "Top Level Functions", which is different than global variables. The answer to the linked question mentions top-level functions as one of the things not supported, but it's buried, and you really have to read carefully to find it. I actually read that question and answer when I was searching, and passed it by as not answering my question, so I bet others will do the same.

Comment: @DuncanC: The other question is called "Swift globals in objective c", that covers both global variables and global functions. Also an answer to your question would be identical to the other answer. That's how I see it, perhaps others want to chime in with comments and/or reopen votes.

Comment: @MartinR, Fair enough. To *me*, the term globals makes me think of global variables but not global functions. I just edited the linked question and renamed it "Swift globals *and global functions* in Objective-C." That way if people search on global functions (or top-level functions, as they're also called" will find that thread more easily.