# Objective-c doesn't see methods of Swift class

Tags: objective-c, swift, class, methods

Currently i need to use my Swift global variables in Objective-c code. These are my variables:

```
public var Name = [String]()
public var Author = [String]()
public var Url = [String]()
```

This is a class that returns my public variables:

```
@objc class AppConstant: NSObject {
   private override init() {}
   class func name() -> [String] { return Name }
   class func author() -> [String] { return Author}
   class func url() -> [String] { return Url}
}
```

My Objective-C code:

```
@implementation SecondViewController
   NSArray *urlArray;
   NSArray *nameArray;
   NSArray *authorArray;


   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       urlArray = [AppConstant url];
       nameArray = [AppConstant name];
       authorArray = [AppConstant author];


   }

@end
```

I think everything should be okay, but it returns error

> No known class method for selector 'url'/'name'/'author'.

Can someone explain where is error.
I did everything as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26463487/swift-globals-and-global-functions-in-objective-c), but it doesnt works. Hope someone will help me

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You use `@objcMembers` next to `class` if you want to expose the entire class to objective-c and `@objc` next to the method you want exposed for single methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `@objc` added to any property or method that you want exposed to Objective-C.

```
@objc class AppConstant: NSObject {
   private override init() {}

   @objc class func name() -> [String] { return Name }
   @objc class func author() -> [String] { return Author}
   @objc class func url() -> [String] { return Url}
}
```

Or you can use `@objcMembers` if you want to expose all non-private properties and methods:

```
@objcMembers class AppConstant: NSObject {
   private override init() {}

   class func name() -> [String] { return Name }
   class func author() -> [String] { return Author}
   class func url() -> [String] { return Url}
}
```

This is a change in Swift 4 from Swift 3. And note that the old question you linked is 4 years old. Swift has changed a lot since then.

Comment: @Sh_Khan In a now deleted comment, the OP claimed this solution fixed their problem which is why they accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import

```
#import "productName-Swift.h"
```

Comment: is it necessary to import main.m in that project? Because my project is Swift based so my App delegate file is also swift hence main.m doesnt work